# jQuery animation problems in ie6-8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation, jquery-animate, margin

I have the following [jsfildde](http://jsfiddle.net/cLy8s/4/).

I got the following probelms:

1. ie6 & ie7: the animation is bouncing for some reason, and there's
   **UNEEDED/UNWANTED** margin between `#awards` to the upper elements. (compare the differences between other browser, for instance: chrome).
2. ie8: the marginTop animation is not working, I tested it for a while and figured that the background changing cause the problem (look at the comment in the jsfiddle, at the JavaScript area).

I will appriciate your help.
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I found similar problem to mine in [other website](http://www.inventpartners.com/ie8_margin_top_bug) which will help to explain my problem better. - nothing of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the other website I found, I figured that the margin collapses and in order to fix the problem in ie8 used padding instead.

to fix the problem in ie6-7, I used micro-clearfix:

```
.clear:before, .clear:after{content:"";display:table;}
.clear:after{clear:both;}
.clear{zoom:1;}
```

and placed it correctly.